# MDX query to order (and topfilter) results after/with a crossjoin

Tags: ssas, mdx, cross-join

I would like to order a set of results in an MDX query which also includes a crossjoin.

I have the following measures and dimensions:

- [Measures].[Starts]
- [Framework].[Framework Name]
- [Framework].[Pathway Name]

I would like to create a list of the (corresponding) Framework and Pathway names that correspond to the top 25 numbers of [Measures].[Starts].

I have managed to output a FULL list of results using:

```
select [Measures].[Starts] on COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Framework].[Pathway Name].Children})}), 
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Framework].[Framework Name].Children})})
) on ROWS
from [DataCube]
```

to create the following example output:
[image: example table required]

However, I need it to be sorted by the starts in descending order (and preferably only keep the top 25 results).  I have tried almost everything and have failed.  A google search didn't find any results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you stumble across the `TopCount` function?

```
select [Measures].[Starts] on COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
    TopCount
        (
        CrossJoin
            (
            Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Framework].[Pathway Name].Children})}), 
            Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Framework].[Framework Name].Children})})
            ), 
        25, 
        [Measures].[Starts]
        ) on ROWS
from [DataCube]
```

Here's the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx).

H2H

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't found that useful function.  It does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency it is better to order the set before using the `TopCount` function:

```
WITH 
SET [SetOrdered] AS
  ORDER(
     {DrilldownLevel([Framework].[Pathway Name].Children)} 
    *{DrilldownLevel([Framework].[Framework Name].Children)}
    ,[Measures].[Starts]
    ,BDESC
  )
SET [Set25] AS
  TOPCOUNT(
     [SetOrdered]
    ,25
  )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Starts] on 0,
NON EMPTY 
  [Set25] on 1
FROM [DataCube];
```

Comment: Just curious - how is this more efficient? Caching makes absolutely no difference here. Secondly instead of a `TopCount,` you could have used `Head`. That would have scored a bit better on the performance side.

Comment: @SouravA I'm unsure if it has been fixed since 2008R2 but the general rule of thumb is _do not use the third argument of TopCount_ ... order the set before hand: the ordered set will then be stored in a fixed array of cells in the cube space and TopCount knows exactly where to look: I can find references if you need them?

Comment: @SouravA I might be getting confused with Rank function. In here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2006/03/14/ranking-in-mdx.aspx Mosha says at the end of the post _"The way to express this query plan in MDX, is to create a named set. Named sets in MDX are always static, i.e. they are evaluated in the context in which they were defined (note that static doesn’t mean materialized, for example CrossJoin can be perfectly static, but it is never materialized). And the hash index is built on top of the static set."_ ... weather this can also help with TopCount - maybe

Comment: @SouravA - please have your say with this non-question - I've down-voted and marked to close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251060/mdx-query-function-to-get-first-member-only. We need to start policing the mdx quetions a bit more as it seems to be a dumping ground for non-questions and vague rubbish.

Comment: Agree to that. Have voted that question for closure.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a neat way of doing it.